# Is there any restriction in generating the maximum number of keys for google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have generated a Google map key by login as a user1@gmail.com . Is there any restriction in generating the number of keys for each user. Since we have 2 different domains and i need to generate key for that too.

Actually i am not sure about of how many keys the person who used this id has created..
And is there any way to find of how many keys had already been created for the same account previously???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#keysystem :

> In order to register for a Google Maps API key, you must sign in to your Google Account and agree to our Terms of Service. There is no limit to the number of keys you may obtain under a single account.
>
> For most applications we recommend that you simply register your domain name. Your key will be valid for that domain, its subdomains, all URLs on hosts in those domains, and all ports on those hosts.